# How to calculate the cumulative probability for discrete random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, discrete-data

I am trying to calculate the **cumulative probability** for this given question:

**Q:**

A tree farming company is testing how many items customers purchase during their visits. Based on many results, the probability distribution below was determined for the discrete random variable X = number of pieces of information remembered (during a fixed time period).

- Given that the person purchases **at least 2 items** from the tree farm, what is the **probability** that they purchase a total of **6 items**?

[image]

- My answer is `.42`
- I calculated it from this : `p(>=2)= .18+.10+.07+.05+.02 =.42`
- But when I reviewed the answer I found that this answer is **wrong** and suggest to review **conditional probability**!

I searched a lot but all examples I found calculate the answer from the same equation as I did, but I am sure there is something wrong and makes this answer wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply the Bayes rule:
$$P(X=6|X\geq 2)=\frac{P(X\geq2|X=6)P(X=6)}{P(X\geq 2)}$$

$P(X\geq2|X=6)=1$, $P(X=6)$ is on your table, and $P(X\geq 2)$ is what you've calculated as $0.42$.

**Addition**: The numerator of the Bayes rule corresponds to $P(X\geq2\cap X=6)$ and it turns into conditional probability formula which is demonstrated in the other answer.

Comment: Why is Bayes' rule needed at all?  To apply it, you have to answer a different question and then convert that answer into the needed one!

Comment: tbh, we don’t need to as per other answer, it’s just another way of calculation.

Comment: I revised it again and your concept is right, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You correctly computed the probability of $X \geq 2 = 0.42$. The question is asking to compute $P(X=6|X\geq 2)$.

By the definition of conditional expectation:

$$P(X=6|X\geq 2) = \frac{P(X=6 \cap X \geq 2) }{P(X\geq 2)} = \frac{P(X=6)}{P(X\geq 2)}$$

since the event $X=6$ is included in $X \geq 2$.

Comment: I think it is now resemble to the correct answer